# Adicionando efeitos nos textos no Owl Carousel usando animate css

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

Faz tempo que tento adicionar animações de textos da biblioteca [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) ao [Owl Carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/), para deixar os Slider cada vez mais bonitos e elegantes, no entanto não consigo, só funcionar o primeiro slider assim que carrega a página, quando eu passo para frente os textos ficam estáticos.

Eu achei um [exemplo](https://codepen.io/radimby/pen/YpEJQP) na internet que seria quase o que eu precisava, só que eu não entendi muito bem o código e ele **não da opção de usar o *data-wow-delay***, queria saber se tem como fazer isso só que usando a estrutura tradicional, até porque eu vou depois puxar essas opções do Wordpress através de campos personalizados.

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

    <div class="item">
        <h4 class="wow fadeInDown">Slide 1</h4>
        <p class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.8s">Cras a elementum dolor. Praesent aliquam sapien ac eros semper ullamcorper. Sed imperdiet enim at sodales suscipit. Aenean eget faucibus ipsum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <h4 class="wow fadeInLeft">Slide 2</h4>
        <p class="wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="1.5s">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc id dolor pulvinar, mollis orci vitae, molestie elit. Maecenas scelerisque ipsum nibh, id imperdiet nulla lobortis nec.</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solução que usei foi inserindo o animation quando a class active estiver presente Ex.:

.item.active {
 animation: exemplo ....
}

Mas nesse caso criei a animação na mão.

Comment: Na mão fica muito engessado